# My Java program - find path - does not output anything

Tags: java

I wrote a recursive program to print path between points but does not print anything!!

```
public static void find(int a, int b, int [][] myArray) 
    {
        System.out.print("thisWay " + a + " ");
        if (myArray[a][b] != 0) 
        {
            int point = myArray[a][b];
            find(a, point, myArray);
            System.out.print("thisWay " + point + " ");
            find(point, b, myArray);
        }
        System.out.print("thisWay " + b + " ");
    }
```

Here is my main;

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        int[][] myArray = new int[][]
        {
           {7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 8, 3, 0, 7},
           {7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 8, 0, 2, 7},
           {0, 4, 5, 1, 1, 8, 0, 1, 5},
        };
        find(2, 4, myArray);
    }
```

Comment: Is doesn't print _anything_?  There's no output at all?  How are you calling `find(...)` the first time around?

Comment: What is your main code? When are you calling this method?

Comment: ooops just forgot to add my main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if this point is not out of your array boundaries, then check if this point is not equal to zero. 
something like this:

```
public class Main  {
      static int x=0;
public static void find(int a, int b, int [][] myArray) throws InterruptedException 
{
    System.out.println("thisWay " + a + " ");
    if (myArray.length>a&&(myArray[0].length>b&&myArray[1].length>b&&myArray[2].length>b)&&myArray[a][b] != 0&&x<100) 
    {
            x++;
        int point = myArray[a][b];
        find(a, point, myArray);
        System.out.print("thisWay " + point + " ");
        find(point, b, myArray);
    }else{
    System.out.print("thisWay " + b + " ");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{   
    int[][] myArray = new int[][]
    {
       {7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 8, 3, 0, 7},
       {7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 8, 0, 2, 7},
       {0, 4, 5, 1, 1, 8, 0, 1, 5},
    };
    System.out.println(myArray.length);
    find(1, 2, myArray);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The I/O for `stdout` is normally buffered, which can prevent output from displaying immediately (`stderr` isn't),  The [`System.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) instance of `PrintStream` is generally line buffered as well.

The easiest way to flush the buffer is normally to print a `'\n'` (e.g. `System.out.print("some text...\n")` or `System.out.println("some text...")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `System.out.println()` instead of all your `System.out.print()` statements, that should flush it to the console.

Besides that you should be careful at 2 things:

- array bounds checking

  if a = 2, b = 5 => point = 8, the next call you'll try myArray[8][5] which should give an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

  Sol: send the bounds of the array as params to your find method and check that a and b are in that bounds
- recursive level checking

  there are chances your program will just loop indefinitely searching in that array, so you'll probably get a StackOverflow exception at same point

  Sol: add a parameter `depth` that specifies how "deep" you want to go recursively, at each recursive call, decrement it, and every time you enter the find() method check that it's `> 0`

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, but it's at least printing out values until it reaches the error.  System.out may be buffering on your system.  Flush it by calling `System.out.flush()` after every print.